# Android custom List row with buttons onclick get index

Tags: android, android-listview, imagebutton, onclicklistener

I created a list view with a custom list row. That list row contains a image view with four imagebuttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 <ImageView
     android:padding="2dip"
     android:id="@+id/list_image"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="200dip"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:src="@drawable/test" 
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

 <LinearLayout
     android:paddingTop="5dip"         
     android:id="@+id/linear"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_image"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/list_image"
     android:layout_below="@+id/list_image"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/copyLink"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:src="@drawable/copy"
         android:background="@color/white"
         />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/visitHP"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:src="@drawable/website"
         android:background="@color/white" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/delete"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:src="@drawable/delete"
         android:background="@color/white" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/share"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_social_share"
         android:background="@color/white" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

As a pic:

[image]

Now i would like to add to each of the buttons a onclicklistener where i can get the index it of the row or the object of the row.

I tried to implement the OnClickListener to my ArrayAdapter:

```
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    public void onclick(View v) {
       int img = v.getId();
    }
```

But with this i wont get the index of the row.

How should i approach this problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `button.setTag()` in `getView()`

And `v.getTag()` in `onClick()`

Answer (score 0):

it works in this way:

```
public void onclick(View v) {
   int id = v.getId();
   switch(id) {
        case R.id.share: .... break;
        case R.id.delete:
           ...
}
```

Comment: with that i only know what button was pressed but not the index of the row